# Why this (duplicated) question was downvoted while others were not?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

This question

- [Can custom attributes be limited to specified types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21640408/340760)

Got downvoted. I don't see anything wrong with it. It is clear what is being asked. So why was it downvoted?

Notice that there are many duplicated questions and none of them were downvoted.

Comment: Well, it's a little light on detail.  I would imagine most folks feel that it lacks research effort, especially given the abundance of duplicate targets.

Comment: Honestly, it was downvoted *because it was downvoted*. We can only guess why it was downvoted, none of us know for sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know *why* it was downvoted, but a very strong argument can be made that it was the right thing to do. Entering the title of the downvoted question,

> Can custom attributes be limited to specified types c#

into Google [turns up a perfect duplicate from 2011.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382536/allow-a-custom-attribute-only-on-specific-type) The OP could literally have found it in less time than it took to ask the question.

If that isn't lack of research, I don't know what is.

Comment: Searching for [Allow a custom Attribute only on specific type](https://www.google.com/search?q=Allow+a+custom+Attribute+only+on+specific+type) shows a question from almost a year ago [How to make .NET attribute only valid on certain types](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4959863/340760) yet this one has 5 upvotes. So from some point [so] started to do this? Is this a good practice now?

Comment: @BrunoLM some users, myself included, are much in favour of downvoting questions that could have been trivially Googled. Other users aren't. Either way, it's definitely not forbidden and you will occasionally see it happening.

Comment: Ok, well, I guess I will stick with Jeff and love duplicates http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Comment: @BrunoLM the two views don't exclude each other. When Jeff talked about embracing *some* duplication, I'm sure he didn't mean 5,000 of the same question, where 10 seconds of Googling could have turned up a perfect original. Those dupes also tend to be poorly linked to each other, and are often answered with wildly varying quality.

Comment: @BrunoLM that said, you of course did the most important, right thing: find some good originals. If in doubt, that's always the best choice, no question about that.